# Custom FrontEndToken calls

Tags: front-end, eventhandler, event-detection

So I've been playing with `FrontEndTokens` recently and discovered that there are some of them that don't seem to have a standard-usage way of being called. For example, the `"Tab"` token isn't called when the tab key is pressed, but is captured by the `{"MenuCommand","Tab"}` event binding, which makes it ripe for abuse as a custom event. That is, if it really doesn't have a common usage, it should be possible to use it as a place holder for a function that will be performed by whatever event handlers. Tkinter in python has this sort of thing via a virtual event caller.

That led me to wondering if it's possible to construct personalized `FrontEndTokens` that I could use as `EventHandler` callbacks.

I'm afraid the answer to this is probably no, given that some of the simple test I've run (e.g. trying `NotebookEventActions -> {{"MenuCommand", "CustomEvent"} :> Print[1]}` haven't worked) but if this were possible it would extend the UI capabilities of Mathematica dramatically.

Comment: So you want an EventHandler to capture custom tokens. How to you want to trigger them?

Comment: My thought was to use `FrontEndTokenExecute` and a `{"MenuCommand",token}`. The idea is to call the event myself and have it be caught by an event handler, for example, have like `"MouseClicked"` and `"MouseExited"` call `FrontEndTokenExecute["VirtualEvent"]`. Basically I want to emulate the tkinter virtual event / event_generate mechanism.

Comment: Ok, but how would event handlers know that they should react or not? Because if every EH should then you can just run `event[]` and `Dynamics` can catch that.

Comment: Obviously I could just call a function if I have just one event handler, but say there are two in nested focus. The first could do `event1[]` on the `"CustomEvent"` call and the second could do `event2[]`. This is why tkinter allows you to register virtual events. I get what you're saying, though, wondering which event handlers would catch such a call, but I figure it's the same as how `EventHandler` or `CellEventActions` behave with `"MenuCommand"` tokens. Only event handlers with current focus should catch them.

Comment: The trick would be to have something like `Dynamic[customEventSymbol; action;Spacer[0], TrackedSymbols :> {customEventSymbol}]` as a "listner" and FrontEndTokenExecute translated to `customEventSymbol++` or something.

Comment: Well yeah, that's what I do currently, but this would be more convenient.

Comment: By the way, a potentially cleaner listener can be constructed using `DynamicWrapper`. Just do `DynamicWrapper[eventHandlerExpr, customEventSymbol; action, TrackedSymbols :> {customEventSymbol}]`. That way you can just put the expression you were going to wrap `EventHandler` around in there. Obviously it also works with `Spacer[0]` to make an invisible listener, too.

Comment: Yes, I know, I just don't like it ;) I find `Dynamic` more readable, the more that they changed something and it doesn't behave as `Dynamic[expr; Refresh[e, None]]`, so it is better now, but the fact its documentation sucks repels me.